# Set minimum number of steps in line chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I just implemented some line charts for my data when I ran across a problem. I have to show daily order data over the last month. There can be months without any orders of the specific product but there can be months with a lot of orders.

That's what I have under `options`:

```
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            callback: function (value) { if (Number.isInteger(value)) {return value; } }
        }
    }]
}
```

I use the `callback` function to make sure the y-axis is only displaying integers. The problem is now that if I leave it like this and I don't have any data to show, it only shows one step (which looks weird):

[image]

I tried using the `max: 10` option but then data gets cut if I have more than 10 orders. I couldn't find any option like `minSteps: 10` or something like that. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a second dataset with all the values being 10 and then make it transparent non hitable so no tooltip shows and hide it in the legend:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        borderColor: 'blue'
      },
      {
        label: 'filler',
        data: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        pointHitRadius: 0,
        radius: 0,
        hoverRadius: 0,
        borderColor: '#00000000'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: (lEl) => (lEl.text !== 'filler')
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

You can use the [`suggestedMax`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings) option, this will make it that it will always show 10 as max unless the data goes above it, then it will adjust the max to whatever the data needs automatically.

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          suggestedMax: 10
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a less "hacky" way to achieve this. Nevertheless it works and I take what I can get, thank you!

Comment: Just thought about a better way, updated answer

Comment: I've tried `suggestedMax` before (didn't work). I guess I used it wrong. Now it works, thanks for the update!

Answer (score -1):

Adding to answer/comments presented by @LeeLenalee I updated code to `chart.js` **v.3x**

Hence, I would recommend:

1. **update** to latest version of `chart.js` **v3.5.1**:
   in code you have both links
   **improved performance** and **new options**, expecially if data contains **dates** as in your case.
   (**v3.x** not backwards compatible with **v2.x**)
2. **use** [Time Cartesian Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html)
   note difference between "**time**" (equidistance) and "**timeseries**" (according whether or not there is a datapoint)
   and you would have to add `momentjs` and `chartjs-adapter-moment` (see code snippet) or add `luxon` etc ... as suggested by @LeeLenalee
   (x-Axis daily view, weekly, monthly, annual - `moment.js` handles the filtering). Comes in handy for you

Please advise if following environment and data structure is correct (I guessed your data structure):

```js
let yourDataJson = [{x: '2021-08-13', y: 20.2},{x: '2021-08-15', y: 16},{x: '2021-08-19', y: 9},{x: '2021-08-23', y: 35},{x: '2021-09-02', y: 2}];

let yourData = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Orders: Product A',
    data: yourDataJson,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,1)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)',
    fill: true
  }
  ]
};

let yourOptions = {
  scales: {
    x: { // <-- v3.x now object "{", not array "[{" anymore
      type: 'timeseries', // <-- try "time" and "timeseries" to see difference
      time: {
        unit: 'day', // <-- set 'hour' / 'day' / 'week' / 'month' or 'year'
        displayFormats: {
          hour: 'h:mm a',
          day: 'ddd, MMM DD, YYYY',
          week: 'dddd',
          month: 'MMM'
        },
        tooltipFormat: 'dddd, MMM DD, YYYY' // <-- new in v3.x
      },
      ticks: {
        minRotation: 80, // avoiding overlapping of x-Axis ticks
        maxRotation: 90
      }
    },
    y: { // <-- v3.x now object "{", not array "[{" anymore
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: function (value) {
          if (Number.isInteger(value)) return value;
        }
      },
      suggestedMin: 0,
      // the data maximum used for determining the ticks is Math.max(dataMax, suggestedMax)
      suggestedMax: 10
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: yourData,
  options: yourOptions
});

document.querySelector('#btnTime').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myChart.options.scales['x'].type = 'time';
  myChart.update();
});
document.querySelector('#btnTimeseries').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myChart.options.scales['x'].type = 'timeseries';
  myChart.update();
});
```

```html
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script> -->

<!-- get the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.1 -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<!-- for x-Axis type 'time' or 'timeseries' to work, you need additional libraries -->
<!-- (like moment.js and its adapter) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>

<button id='btnTime'>time</button>
<button id='btnTimeseries'>timeseries</button>

<canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Better off using luxon or date-fns, way lower performance impacting libs, also this will lead to the same issue that it doesnt show full integers and if you only show the full integers it only shows 0 and 1 and thats what he excplicitly didnt want

Comment: Also `stepSize: 10`  does not force a minimum of 10 units to be shown, it makes it so that between each tick there is 10, so if your axis range goes from 1 to 100 you have 10 ticks but if your axis range goes from 1 to 20 you only have 2 ticks which still gives the same problem of having a big gap https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/w0cxq8r9/1/